# jQuery stars rating message reflects on all items

Tags: javascript, jquery, rating

I have created a stars rating in jQuery but for example when I rate the first item (for instance 2 stars) the message reflecting this rating will show on all items even if not rated.
This is the jQuery portion that creates the HTML

```
'<section  class ="rating-widget"><div class="rating-stars text-center"><ul id="stars"><li class="star" title="Poor" data-value="1"><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i></li><li class="star" title="Fair" data-value="2"><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i></li><li class="star" title="Good" data-value="3"><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i></li><li class="star" title="Excellent" data-value="4"><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i></li><li class="star" title="Perfect" data-value="5"><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i></li></ul></div>' +
                    '<div class="success-box"><div class="clearfix"></div><div class="text-message"></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></section>';
```

This is the jQuery code that creates the rating functionality

```
  /* 1. Visualizing things on Hover - See next part for action on click */
            $('#stars li').on('mouseover', function() {
                var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently mouse on

                // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
                $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e) {
                    if (e < onStar) {
                        $(this).addClass('hover');
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass('hover');
                    }
                });

            }).on('mouseout', function() {
                $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e) {
                    $(this).removeClass('hover');
                });
            });


            /* 2. Action to perform on click */
            $('#stars li').on('click', function() {
                var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently selected
                var stars = $(this).parent().children('li.star');

                for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
                    $(stars[i]).removeClass('selected');
                }

                for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
                    $(stars[i]).addClass('selected');
                }

                // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
                var ratingValue = parseInt($('#stars li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);
                var msg = "";
                if (ratingValue > 1) {
                    msg = "Thanks! You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
                } else {
                    msg = "We will improve ourselves. You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
                }
                responseMessage(msg);

            });

            function responseMessage(msg) {
                $('.success-box').fadeIn(200);
                $('.success-box div.text-message').html("<span>" + msg + "</span>");
            }
```

This image shows how the message is displaying on all items
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWQTP.jpg)

Comment: If you re-use that "rating widget" HTML more than once, you end up with an invalid DOM.  An id value should only be used once on a page if you want things to work properly.

Comment: Also you should declare the variable `i` in your click handler, or use jQuery `.each()` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get more specific with your jQuery. Your `$('#stars li')` is most likely too general. Maybe group the items stars in separate `divs` such that they can be referenced more specifically. If your jQuery effects too many elements, it just means that your id's and/or class references are too general.